# Use ADFS-based authentication inside ASP.NET Core to access a SQL Server using Windows authentication?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, windows-authentication, adfs

I have a SQL Server that's configured to use Windows authentication. The database administrator uses AD users and groups to grant / deny permissions on certain tables and procedures.

I also have web apps that communicate with ASP.NET Core Web APIs. These apps uses ADFS for authentication, so basically all users are registered into AD.

In a few of those APIs, I want to access data from SQL Server on behalf of the authenticated AD user, which means I can't use SQL Server authentication. I also can't use the integrated security mode, as it will then assume the identity of the account that runs the ASP.NET Core service.

My next thought was that I should try punctually impersonating the user, but I couldn't find a single working example of transforming an ADFS token into a `WindowsIdentity` object.

So how should I go with this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Suggest to your DBA that a better approach is to grant permissions based on *database roles*, not directly using AD accounts. For one thing, roles and their permissions belong to the database and will survive migration to another environment (which is relevant even if you decide to use AD forever; think new domain); logins will not. It also frees the database permission logic from having to know how authentication happens, which is properly none of its concern. This allows you to have both AD auth and SQL auth, and source control databases and their permissions without embedding accounts.

Comment: @JeroenMostert IIRC I think he already does that. He creates roles which he then subscribe AD groups to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the idea of ADFS is that it provides a token that ISN'T your Windows credentials on purpose. Imagine if you federated your domain with another service's so your users could login, but whatever service you allow it to connect to can now impersonate your windows credentials? They could use that to gain access back to your network.

Now, if your Web API runs under an account with sufficient permissions, you could simply have it impersonate the user based on username.

With that said, I can't say that it is the recommended way of securing database access, and you should really just have a SQL account for the Web API to access that database and provide information to the end user.

You can set up what's called Identity Delegation where your web app would request another impersonation token from ADFS on behalf of your end user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/design/when-to-use-identity-delegation

Comment: *They could use that to gain access back to your network* isn't that something I can control using ADFS Application groups? So that only my API would have the necessary claims to be able to do impersonation? Sorry if it's a silly question, I am very green with ADFS.

Comment: *Now, if your Web API runs under an account with sufficient permissions, you could simply have it impersonate the user based on username.* Just the username? Won't the password be required as well?

Comment: *you should really just have a SQL account for the Web API* this is out of my hands, I'm afraid. Furthermore, I really don't see how I could talk my boss out of using AD for security control, let alone spend tons of money coding our own users and groups infrastructure, which we'd STILL have to map to AD somehow because it's how everything else works.

Comment: I've added in a bit about Identity Delegation that may suit your needs. However, no, you still can't directly change an ADFS access token to a windows credentials, nor would you want to because that is a huge security risk. Active Directory should be used to secure the front end. The web server should only return data that the user is allowed to see. But the web server should communicate with the SQL server using a service account. Giving users direct access to a database is itself a different security risk especially if they don't know what they are doing in SQL and won't log in directly